# ExpandableListView utilizando RecyclerView?

Tags: android

Olá, precisei algumas vezes criar um `recyclerview` que tivesse o mesmo princípio do `expandablelistview` para isso, sempre fiz uso desta [lib](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view)

Ela resolve o problema. Porém esta é uma boa solução?

Answer (score 2):

Sim, se resolve o seu problema e é fácil de ser usada e implementada, é sim uma boa solução, visto que hoje não temos isso no `RecyclerView`.

Nos meus projetos que tenho, em alguns momentos precisei fazer isso, mas optei por fazer manualmente sem utilizar a biblioteca, pois dependendo para que você vai utilizar, é relativamente fácil fazer.

Por exemplo, eu tenho um projeto aqui utilizado para restaurantes, onde você tem uma lista de produtos e cada produto da lista tem sua lista de preços. Para implementar isso eu coloquei apenas um `RecyclerView` com um `Adapter` e dentro deste `Adapter` no `onBindViewHolder` eu coloquei para criar o `Adapter` da lista de preços. No meu layout de produtos, eu tenho um novo `RecyclerView` para lista de preços, sendo assim, os preços são carregados dentro de cada produto. Quando o usuário clica em um produto, eu mudo a visualização da lista de preços que está nele para visível, funcionando como uma lista expansível.

Tudo isso seria facilmente implementado utilizando essa biblioteca, mas para evitar muitas dependências, e como é simples para o meu caso, eu decidi por essa forma.